# Equation that handles diminishing returns

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've tried desperately to figure this out, but to no avail.

I need an equation that will effectively reduce a number by $0.2 \%$ each time it is added to itself (The original number).

In other words, the first number will be $100$, then the second number will be $199.8 = (100 + 99.8)$, and then the third number will be $299.4 = (100 + 99.8 + 99.6)$.

I've tried things like $Y = 100 * X - 0.2 * (X - 1)$ but that doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you made the numerical example by yourself or was it given ?

Comment: I wanted to create a system where efficiency was lost with each purchase of something.  The original problem started with the first purchase being 0.01, and the next being 0,2% less effective, so it would cap out at 2.5 and any further purchases would actually hinder you.  Long story short, I made the example myself.

Comment: The numerical example of your comment is not comprehensible for me. But in your question you wrote, that the added number is the initial (orgininal) number (X) reduced by n-times a factor: $X\cdot (1-na)$.Is this right ? Have a look at my answer and decide if it´s satisfy your conditions.

Comment: @calculus Yes, I believe that is right.  The first time reduces the original number by 0%, the second time (n = 2) reduces the original number by 0.2%, and so forth.  I think I'm getting close with Y = 1/10 * (1001 * X - X^2)

Comment: Close is not exact. Do you understand my answer ? Or do have you any questions about it ?

Comment: I attempted to plug some numbers in, but I was not getting the results that I wanted.  I think I'm just incompetent with Sigma, though.

Comment: I have made an edit of my answer and have posted a numerical example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your $100$ be x and $a=0.2$. Then you have the following sequences:

$b_1=(1-0a)x, b_2=(1-1a)x, b_3=(1-2a)x,\ldots , b_n=(1-(n-1)a)x$

The sum of these sequences is $n\cdot x - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i\cdot a=n\cdot x - a\cdot \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i$.

$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i=\frac{(n-1)\cdot n}{2}$ is a well known [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF).

$\color{blue}{\texttt{numerical example}}$

$a=0.2\%\cdot 100=0.2, \ x=100, \ n=3$

The formula in total is

$n\cdot  x-a\cdot \frac{(n-1)\cdot n}{2}=3\cdot 100-0.2\cdot\frac{(3-1)\cdot 3}{2}=300-0.2\cdot\frac{2\cdot 3}{2}=300-0.6=\boxed{299.4}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_0$ be the first number and $\alpha$ be the geometric ratio.

Then we have

$$x_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n} x_0 \alpha^i = x_0 \frac{\alpha^{n+1}-1}{\alpha - 1}.$$ For the example you gave we have $\alpha = 0.998$ and $x_0 = 100$.

For those of you who don't like $0$ based indexing, we have

$$y_n = y_1 \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha^{i-1} = y_1 \frac{\alpha^{n}-1}{\alpha - 1}.$$

Note that $99.8$ less $0.2\%$ is $99.6004$ not $99.6$ as stated in the question.

Comment: Perhaps I don't fully understand it and am doing it wrong, but upon trying to check it with plugging in 2, it gave me 198 instead of the 199.8 I was looking for.

Comment: For n=2 I get $299,4004$. This is not the result what it should be.

Comment: Note that it starts fro $x_0$ : 100, 199.8, 299.4004

Comment: @trueblueanil But it should be 299.4, not 299.4004.

Comment: @calculus: "reduce a **number** by 0.2% each time it is added to **itself**. If **itself** means 199.8, then shouldn't **number** also  mean 199.8 when reducing the second time ?

Comment: @trueblueanil Ok maybe from the wording you are right. But the numerical example is different. I think the question needs a clarification.

Comment: @calculus: That's true ! Confusion worse confounded ! :)